# Colour picker from image upload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering if anyone knows of some html code that would allow a user to upload an image and it would generate a bunch of colours from that image, Kinda like this does here `http://www.cssdrive.com/imagepalette/`

We could do with automating this onto our site rather than a third party site.

Anyone know of anything that exists like this? Or am i asking for the world?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this project on Github?

[Color Thief](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/)

It's a javascript solution. (It depends on two additional libraries: `jquery` and `quantize.js`).

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
colorThief.getPalette(sourceImage, 8);
getPalette(sourceImage[, colorCount, quality])
```

Comment: I am glad this helped you.